# Combine CSS lines into one

Tags: css, stylesheet

I want to define some basic styles that I can combine. Let's say I have a stylesheet that contains the following lines:

```
.whitebackground  {background-color: #ffffff}
.borderblue       {border: solid 1px #0000aa}
```

I'm wondering if there is there a way to include these lines into a new line? Something like:

```
**div.main   {.whitebackground; .borderblue}**
```

The result must be the same as it would be with this line:

```css
div.main  {background-color: #ffffff; border: solid 1px #0000aa}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) library.

They will allow you to include style declaration from one selector to the other.

Using LESS, you syntax will be perfectly valid and work as you want

```
div.main   {
   .whitebackground; 
   .borderblue;
}
```

But, when they are compiled, it will take the optimized form automatically.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. I was hoping to do this without javascript, but I guess this is not possible. Thnx. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

With standard CSS, you can't. However, you can give your div multiple classes.

`<div class="whitebackground borderblue">`

This will apply both sets of css to the div.

By the way, if I were in a pedantic mood, I'd say that names like "whitebackground" and "borderblue" are not very good class names. With classes like that, you could just as well use inline styles. Class names are supposed to convey meaning, intention, structure, emphasis etc. Use names like "special-remark", "important", "sidenote", "highlight" or whatever reason you have for giving your div a white background and blue border.

Comment: I am aware of this possibility, but I was looking for combine it in the stylesheet itself. Thanks anyway. BTW: The stylesheet lines that I mentioned are not the real names or styles.